# how to use multiple datasouce and sessionFactory during a junit runtime test

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit, sessionfactory

How to use multiple datasouce and sessionFactory during a junit runtime test?

I use hibernateDaoTemplate for persistence, and my structure is right down here:

I just want to get, say, products from a different db and then persist them to a different db in ProductStatServiceTest runtime.

Thanks in advance.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/dataSource.xml", "/hibernate.xml", "/applicationContext.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager", defaultRollback = true)
public abstract class GenericTransactionalUnitTest extends   AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
  private Session session;

  protected abstract SessionFactory getSessionFactory();
  ...
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
abstract public class ProductStatUnitTest extends GenericTransactionalUnitTest {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "productStatSessionFactory")
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Resource(name = "productStatDS")
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
         return sessionFactory;
  }
}

public class ProductStatServiceTest extends ProductStatUnitTest {
  @Autowired
  private ProductStatService productStatService;  

  @Test
  public List<ProductStat> testInjection() throws ParseException {
     productStatService.findById(123456); 
  }
..
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Database => 2 session factories and datasources. This currently is not possible in your code.

I assume you have 1 `ProductStatService` but your requirement is that this service will work with *sessionfactoryA* for the 'select' and *sessionfactoryB* for the 'insert'.

Hence, you will need to create (and inject) 2 instances of this service in your unit test and these of course can't be scoped as singletons (assuming you use Spring for DI).
You will have to rewrite some of your code, the actual sessionfactory will need to be injected into the service and not retrieved by `GenericTransactionalUnitTest.getSessionFactory()`.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to create 2 DAO's then this also an option:

```
public class ProductStatDAO extends AbstractHibernateDao {

@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("sessionFactoryA")
private SessionFactory sessionFactoryA;

@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("sessionFactoryB")
private SessionFactory sessionFactoryB;

//called by Spring (init-method)
public void init() {
    if (getSessionFactory() == null) {
        if (sessionFactoryA != null) {
            setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryA);
        } else if (sessionFactoryB != null) {
            setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryB);
        } 
        // else throw exception
    }
}
```

}

You will however still need to inject 2 different instances of this DAO (so scope='prototype') in your service.

Comment: Thanks at first. How can I inject different session factories at one test class? Is your suggestion about keeping sessionFactory in the service class rather than test class?

Comment: Then how can i set different data sources?

Comment: Neither actually, the sessionfactory is used at DAO level; your services should not even be aware that hibernate is used for persistence. Best option is probably to have 2 DAO's (one to retrieve and one to persist productstats) and to inject a different sessionfactory in them (one that is configured for DB-A and one for DB-B). Be aware that 2 DB's can't be used inside 1 transaction unless you have a real (J2EE) transaction manager (like on Websphere or JBoss). If you use Tomcat or Jetty you will have to integrate Atomikos to allow this.